# Remote server returned an error:not found

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am using silverlight web asp.net project (Client) and using WCF service(Server).

I am sending a request to wcf to do some operation, usally it takes more than 25-30mins (This is not an issue for app as it is internal app). When I am running from my local code it is working fine and when I deploy in my local IIS its working.
But when I deploy client in my webserver and wcf in app server I am getting an error 'Remote server returned an error:not found' in client side after 10-13mins bu behind the scenes Stored procedure is running and completed the task but Enduser doesnt either that is completed or not as it is showing above error. 
I increased timeouts to 50mins at client and server side(Sendtime,receieve,open,close) 
changed httpruntime exceptiontimeout to 3600sec
I am breaking my head like anything can you please help on this.﻿

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing a library.  Check every reference and ensure they are all being copied to the host server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, its working for smaller data (Execute reader does take only couple of mins) failing for big data (Execute reader takes 10-15min). So I do not think so I missed any library, correct me if I am wrong